# Select random number from a specific list

Tags: mysql, sql, random

How to get random number `[10, 20, 30, 50]` in MySQL.

I have tried using `ROUND(RAND() * (50 - 10) + 10)` but, this will generate numbers such as `11, 12, 24` which i don't want.

I wonder if this code will:

```
FLOOR((RAND([5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]))
```

but how?

I want to set my quantity column to choose random 10,20,30, or 50. not 11, 12 or other possible number using ROUND(RAND() * (50-10) + 10).

Hope it is clear.

Comment: If you know the numbers you want to generate, then they are not really random, right?  Maybe you can better explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: use a loop not a rand() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you one of the numbers *from a list*:

```
SELECT ELT(FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1, 10, 20, 30, 50);
```

Here 4 is the size of list and one is added since [`ELT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) is one-based.

Answer (score 3):

try this it's working fine

```
ROUND(RAND() * (5-1))*10
```

Comment: that works like charm! thanks .. i modify to ROUND(RAND() * (5-1) + 1)*10 to prevent 0 output

Comment: It will return zero as well. Might have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: This will return 40 though. But more importantly, do not use ROUND function with RAND... otherwise the first and last values will get lesser probability compared to the middle ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you want number that can be devised by 10 use Div and then multiply by 10

SELECT   ((FLOOR(RAND()*(50-10+1))+10) DIV 10 ) * 10 ;